# Decision Tree Binary Classifier shortcut (sorting)

Tags: sorting, machine-learning, tree, decision-tree

Normally, at each node of the decision tree, we consider all features and all splitting points for each feature. We calculate the difference between the entropy of the entire node and the weighted avg of the entropies of potential left and right branches, and the feature + splitting feature_value that gives us the greatest entropy drop is chosen as the splitting criterion for that particular node.

Can someone explain why the above process, which requires (2^m -2)/2 tries **for each feature** at each node, where m is the number of distinct feature_values at the node, is the same as **trying ONLY m-1 splits**:

1. sort the m distinct feature_values by the percentage of 1's of the samples within the node that takes that feature_value for that feature.
2. Only try the m-1 ways of splitting the sorted list.

This 'trying only m-1 splits' method is mentioned as a 'shortcut' in the article below, which (by definition of 'shortcut') means the results of the two methods which differ drastically in runtime are exactly the same.

The quote:"For regression and binary classification problems, with K = 2 response classes, there is a computational shortcut [1]. The tree can order the categories by mean response (for regression) or class probability for one of the classes (for classification). Then, the optimal split is one of the L – 1 splits for the ordered list. "

The article:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/splitting-categorical-predictors-for-multiclass-classification.html?s_tid=gn_loc_drop&requestedDomain=uk.mathworks.com

Note that I'm talking only about categorical variables.

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone explain why the above process, which requires (2^m -2)/2 tries for each feature at each node, where m is the number of distinct feature_values at the node, is the same as trying ONLY m-1 splits:

The answer is simple: both procedures just aren't the same. As you noticed, splitting in the exact way is an NP-hard problem and thus hardly feasible for any problem in practice. Moreover, due to overfitting that would usually be not the optimal result in terms of generaluzation.

Instead, the exhaustive search is replaced by some kind of greedy procedure which goes like: sort first, then try all ordered splits. In general this leads to different results than the exact splitting.

In order to improve on the greedy result, one further often applies pruning (which can be seen as another greedy and heuristic method). And never methods like random forests or BART deal with this problem effectively by averaging over several trees -- so that the deviation of a single tree becomes less important.

Comment: Oh, so they are, in fact, not the same thing - I thought there was some math trick that I wasn't seeing. Thanks.